# Jupyter / IPython SList :: Obtaining non-tokenized output from the shell execute operator "!"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-science, jupyter-lab

When shell commands are run within a `Jupyter Notebook Python Cell`, like this:

`output = ! some-shell-command`

each line emitted to the standard output (`stdout`) is captured in a `list` *like* `IPython` data-structure called a `SList`. For instance:

```
output = !echo -e 'line1\nline2\nline3'
print(output) # A IPython SList data-structure.
```

`['line1', 'line2', 'line3']`

Sometimes, however, you want to preserve the original string output format, without tokenization into a list, like this:

`print(output)`

```
line1
line2
line3
```

*Example: For structured JSON output -- which is a string containing many newline characters -- you wouldn't want this tokenization to occur*.

How, then, can I execute shell commands in `Jupyter Notebooks` using the `!` operator, and retrieve un-tokenized output (like above)?

Ideally, the solution would be something native in `Jupyter Notebooks`.

Thank you!

Comment: If it's like a list, you should be able to do `'\n'.join(output)` to get it into a single string.

Comment: @Barmar Of course that worked. LoL =:) Why don't you post that as an answer and I'll upvote it. I'll wait to select it as `the` answer, though, just in case there's a native way to change output format in Jupyter.

Comment: I don't use Jupyter, I don't know how you would print that result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SList` has a number of properties, that return it in various forms:

https://gist.github.com/parente/b6ee0efe141822dfa18b6feeda0a45e5

```
In [151]: ret = !ls *.json                                                                       
In [152]: ret                                                                                    
Out[152]: ['foo1.json', 'foo.json', 'logins.json', 'stack56532806.json']
```

as list

```
In [153]: ret.l                                                                                  
Out[153]: ['foo1.json', 'foo.json', 'logins.json', 'stack56532806.json']
```

as newline separated string:

```
In [154]: ret.n                                                                                  
Out[154]: 'foo1.json\nfoo.json\nlogins.json\nstack56532806.json'
```

as space delimited:

```
In [155]: ret.s                                                                                  
Out[155]: 'foo1.json foo.json logins.json stack56532806.json'
In [156]: type(ret)
```

its docs

```
In [158]: ret?                                                                                   
Type:        SList
String form: ['foo1.json', 'foo.json', 'logins.json', 'stack56532806.json']
Length:      4
File:        /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/utils/text.py
Docstring:  
List derivative with a special access attributes.

These are normal lists, but with the special attributes:

* .l (or .list) : value as list (the list itself).
* .n (or .nlstr): value as a string, joined on newlines.
* .s (or .spstr): value as a string, joined on spaces.
* .p (or .paths): list of path objects (requires path.py package)

Any values which require transformations are computed only once and
cached.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and was the native solution I was hoping for. I revamped the initial question (keeping the same problem statement) so others can find and solve this same issue more easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For those here looking to turn jupyter standard output (`stdout`) which is of type `SList` into `JSON` this is what I did:

```
import json
output = !command  #output is an SList
j_out = json.dumps(output)  #jout is a str
out_dict = json.loads(j_out) #out_dict is a list 
out_dict[i][j]... #to access list elements
```

This assumes that `command` has appropriately formatted output to be processed into a python dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join()` to combine an iterator into a string.

```
"\n".join(output)
```