# Python variable appears to be json but with quotes throughout

Tags: python, jupyter, azure-cli

I'm new to Python; using Jupyter nb here.

When setting a variable to the results of an `az cli` command, I get a json array but one riddled with single quotes.

When I run the command alone, without setting it to a variable, the response is clean json.

**How do I get the variable result as clean json?**

**Example1: (This was fixed by using `.join` as explained in the comments)**

```
new_mi = !az identity create --name $mi_name --resource-group $rg_name --location $rc_location
new_mi
['{',
 '  "clientId": "redacto",',
 '  "clientSecretUrl": "https://control-westus2.identity.azure.net/subscriptions/redacto/resourcegroups/rg_azureFunction/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mi_azureFunction/credentials?tid=redacto&oid=redacto&aid=redacto",',
 '  "id": "/subscriptions/redacto/resourcegroups/rg_azureFunction/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mi_azureFunction",',
 '  "location": "westus2",',
 '  "name": "mi_azureFunction",',
 '  "principalId": "redacto",',
 '  "resourceGroup": "rg_azureFunction",',
 '  "tags": {',
 '    "lang": "python",',
 '    "owner": "redacto",',
 '    "project": "test"',
 '  },',
 '  "tenantId": "redacto",',
 '  "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities"',
 '}']
```

**Example2: Different `az cli` command, but `.join` does not work here**

- I don't think the response, even after the `.join` is valid json due to the message at the beginning.
- How do I skip this and go straight to the json object to `.join`?

```
sa_new = !az storage account create --name $sa_name --resource-group $rg_name --access-tier Cool --default-action Deny --kind StorageV2 --sku Standard_LRS --subscription $sub_id --tags $sa_tags

sa_new

["WARNING: The default kind for created storage account will change to 'StorageV2' from 'Storage' in the future",
 '{',
 '  "accessTier": "Cool",',
 '  "azureFilesIdentityBasedAuthentication": null,',
 '  "creationTime": "2020-05-21T05:28:13.115847+00:00",',
 '  "customDomain": null,',
 '  "enableHttpsTrafficOnly": true,',
 '  "encryption": {',
 '    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",',
 '    "keyVaultProperties": null,',
 '    "services": {',
 '      "blob": {',
 '        "enabled": true,',
 '        "lastEnabledTime": "2020-05-21T05:28:13.193965+00:00"',
 '      },',
 '      "file": {',
 '        "enabled": true,',
 '        "lastEnabledTime": "2020-05-21T05:28:13.193965+00:00"',
 '      },',
 '      "queue": null,',
 '      "table": null',
 '    }',
 '  },',
 '  "failoverInProgress": null,',
 '  "geoReplicationStats": null,',
 '  "id": "/subscriptions/redacto/resourceGroups/redacto/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/redacto",',
 '  "identity": null,',
 '  "isHnsEnabled": null,',
 '  "kind": "StorageV2",',
 '  "largeFileSharesState": null,',
 '  "lastGeoFailoverTime": null,',
 '  "location": "westus2",',
 '  "name": "redacto",',
 '  "networkRuleSet": {',
 '    "bypass": "AzureServices",',
 '    "defaultAction": "Deny",',
 '    "ipRules": [],',
 '    "virtualNetworkRules": []',
 '  },',
 '  "primaryEndpoints": {',
 '    "blob": "https://redacto.blob.core.windows.net/",',
 '    "dfs": "https://redacto.dfs.core.windows.net/",',
 '    "file": "https://redacto.file.core.windows.net/",',
 '    "queue": "https://redacto.queue.core.windows.net/",',
 '    "table": "https://redacto.table.core.windows.net/",',
 '    "web": "https://redacto.z5.web.core.windows.net/"',
 '  },',
 '  "primaryLocation": "westus2",',
 '  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",',
 '  "resourceGroup": "redacto",',
 '  "secondaryEndpoints": null,',
 '  "secondaryLocation": null,',
 '  "sku": {',
 '    "capabilities": null,',
 '    "kind": null,',
 '    "locations": null,',
 '    "name": "Standard_LRS",',
 '    "resourceType": null,',
 '    "restrictions": null,',
 '    "tier": "Standard"',
 '  },',
 '  "statusOfPrimary": "available",',
 '  "statusOfSecondary": null,',
 '  "tags": {',
 '    "owner": "redacto",',
 '    "project": "test"',
 '  },',
 '  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"',
 '}']

sa_new = json.loads("\n".join(sa_new))

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Example3: This command has the same issue, a "WARNING" message at the top makes the response invalid JSON**

```
az_new = !az functionapp create --consumption-plan-location westus --name $af_name --os-type Linux --resource-group $rg_name --runtime python --storage-account $sa_name --disable-app-insights true

az_new

["WARNING: Your Linux function app 'redacto', that uses a consumption plan has been successfullycreated but is not active until content is published usingAzure Portal or the Functions Core Tools.",
 '{',
 '  "availabilityState": "Normal",',
 '  "clientAffinityEnabled": false,',...
```

Comment: Because it gives you each line as an individual string, just join them

Comment: in addition, after having a clean string, if you want to have it as a json object, you could just import json and then json.loads (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: I tried `json.loads(new_mi)`. Results in `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'SList'`

Comment: If you want to work directly with the result, you have to join it back into a string, as in `json.loads("\n".join(new_mi))`

Comment: @tmrlvi, this worked. Thank you. `new_mi = json.loads("\n".join(new_mi))`. Then I was able to access elements of the json object with `new_mi['clientId']`, etc. If you'd like to update your answer, I can accept it. (Was not able to get the `subprocess` answer to work)

Comment: @tmrlvi, could you peek at Example2 in the edited original post? The response from a different `az cli` command has a pesky message that makes the json invalid. The `.join` solution that previously worked, does not in this case.

Comment: I suspect you have both `stdout` and `stderr` stream. You'll have to use `subprocess.Popen` or `os.popen`. I've changed my answer to use `os.popen`.

Comment: I'm still unable to get Example 2 or 3 in the original post to work using `.join` nor `json.dumps`. It seems the error message shown as the first element in the response is preventing proper keying. [Here is someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973053/jupyter-ipython-slist-obtaining-non-tokenized-output-from-the-shell-execute) noting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `!` to run command in Jupyter, it returns the output as a list of rows. A more convenient way might be to use `os.popen` or `subprocess.run` or similar command, and then parse the json.

```
import os
import json

json.loads(os.popen("az identity create --name $mi_name --resource-group $rg_name --location $rc_location
new_mi").read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional effort here, but I cannot get `os.popen` to work either.